# Add markers to a map with Firebase

Tags: kotlin

I want to make an application with Kotlin and Google Maps in which the user can add markers on the Google Map and that these markers are sent to Firebase and other users can see those same markers on the map.

This is what I have done but it is not working well for me.

```
package com.racrapa.displayinglocationapp
        
import android.content.ContentValues
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference

private const val TAG = "MapsActivity"

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    public lateinit var databaseRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private var markers: MutableList<Marker> = mutableListOf()
    private var postListener: ValueEventListener? = null
    var mDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        databaseRef = Firebase.database.reference
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("userlocation")
        database = Firebase.database.reference

    }
```

This is to get the data from Firebase

```
    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        var postListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    val locationlogging = dataSnapshot.child("userlocation").getValue(LocationLogging::class.java)
                    var driverLat=locationlogging?.Latitude
                    var driverLong=locationlogging?.Longitude

                    if (driverLat != null && driverLong != null) {
                        val driverLoc = LatLng(driverLat, driverLong)

                        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(driverLoc).title("Driver")
                        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)

                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Locations accessed from the database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
        }
        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener { latLng ->
            Log.i(TAG, "onMapLongClickListener")
            setMapLongClick(latLng)
        }


    }
```

This is the function of sending coordinates to Firebase

```
    private fun setMapLongClick(latLng: LatLng) {

        if (latLng != null) {
            Log.e("Latitude: ", latLng.latitude.toString() + "longitude: " + latLng.longitude)
            val latlang: MutableMap<String, Double> = HashMap()
            latlang["latitude"] = latLng.latitude
            latlang["longitude"] = latLng.longitude
            mDatabase!!.child("userlocation").push().setValue(latlang)
            onStart()


        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for asking a question on SO. Could you elaborate on what it is that isn't working as expected? What are you getting and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.

I want a user to be able to add a marker at the latitude and longitude where they have clicked on the map (setOnMapLongClick), and this marker can be shared (using Firebase) on the map where other users can see it.

I have tried to do it in many ways, when I press anywhere, a point is usually marked on the map but one in particular, in the same place, not where I clicked. Or just nothing appears.

Thank you! :)